# Clang: Don't optimize a given file

Tags: c++, c, debugging, optimization, clang

When compiling with Clang, I can add the `optnone` attribute to a function to compile it without optimizations

```c
[[clang::optnone]]
void foo() {
    // no optimizations applied in here
    ...
}

void bar() {
    // while other functions are still optimized
}
```

This is really useful when debugging with GDB. On programs that are too large to be practically compiled entirely in debug mode (llvm), I can instead compile with CMake set to `RelWithDebInfo`, add the attribute to some functions of interest, then get a consistent debug in those places without jumping around and fighting inlined values.

Is there any equivalent way to compile all functions in a given file in debug mode, without manually adding the attribute to every function?

Cheers

Comment: You can usually mess with compiler options using `pragma`.

Comment: I use `-Og -g`.  Enough optimizations to make debugging not excruciatingly slow, and enough debugging metadata to make debugging work.

Comment: @MooingDuck: He probably meant "so large that running without optimization is unreasonably slow".  I definitely have had projects where some computational loops need to be optimized in order to be able to debug the rest of the program.

Comment: @MooingDuck yep Ben Voigt has it exactly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Compile your source files individually to object files (this is automatically done with most build setups); then for your particular object file, set custom optimization settings. For example:

```
cc -O3 file1.c -c -o file1.o
cc -O0 -g file2.c -c -o file2.o
```

will optimize only `file1.c` but not `file2.c`. This works for any compiler.

2. Use a range-based optimization pragma, a [Clang extension](https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extensions-for-selectively-disabling-optimization). Write `#pragma clang optimize off` to disable optimizations from that point onward, and `#pragma clang optimize on` to reenable them. For example, simply putting `#pragma clang optimize off` at the top of the file will disable optimizations for the entire file.